# Spacing issue for my calendar and not displaying correct day

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My code is currently working, and displaying the months, but the first row keeps shifting over at least 3 spaces continually untill the first row cannot be seen by the last month. The point of this assignment is to display a yearly calendar using loops and arrays. My output comes out but not under the right section. Any help please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calendar 
 { 
static final int FEBRUARY        = 2;
static final int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;

static int [] daysPerMonth = 
    {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

static String [] months =  
    {"", "  Januray", "February", "   March", "   April",
         "      May", "    June", "    July", "  August", 
        "September", " October", "November", "December"};

public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter the year? (yyyy): "); 
    int year = in.nextInt(); 

    int firstDay = firstDayOfYear(year);

    // February: Check for leap year    
    daysPerMonth [FEBRUARY] = isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28; 

    for (int i=1; i <= MONTHS_PER_YEAR; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n\n      "+months[i]+" "+year);
        printMonth(daysPerMonth[i], firstDay);
        firstDay = firstDayOfNextMonth(daysPerMonth[i], firstDay); 
    }
}

// you must implement this method   
private static void printMonth(int numDays, int firstDay)
{
    int month=1, value=0;
    System.out.println("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa");
    System.out.println("--  --  --  --  --  --  --");
    String spaceControl = "  ";
    int[][] arr = new int[5][7];
    for(int i=0; i<firstDay; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int j=1; j<=numDays; j++){
        System.out.printf("%4d", j);
        if(((j+firstDay)%7==0) || (j==numDays)){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}


// you must implement this method   
private static int firstDayOfNextMonth(int numDays, int firstDay)
{
    int firstOfNext;
    firstOfNext=firstDay+numDays;
        if(firstOfNext%7==0){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Sunday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==1){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Monday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==2){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Tuesday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==3){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Wednsday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==4){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Thursday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==5){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Friday");
        }
        if(firstOfNext%7==6){
            System.out.println("Next month starts on a Saturday");
        }
return firstOfNext;
}

private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year%4 == 0) && (year%100 != 0)) || (year%400 == 0);
}

private static int firstDayOfYear(int year) {
    return (2 * (13) + (3 * (13+1)/5) + (year-1) + ((year-1)/4) 
            - ((year-1)/100) + ((year-1)/400) + 2) % 7;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look very carefully at what you are returning from `firstDayOfNextMonth()`.  It's not really the "first day of next month"...

Try replacing this line in `firstDayOfNextMonth()`:

```
firstOfNext=firstDay+numDays;
```

with this:

```
firstOfNext = (firstDay+numDays) % 7;
```

Comment: I don't understand what to do though to have the first line display correctly